# How to make rpm module work with (non-system) Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an RHEL5/OEL5 64 bit OS with native python-2.4 on it and rpm-python-4.4.2.3-27.0.1.el5 installed.
When doing 'import rpm' with python-2.4 everything works as expected.

I would like (must) to use the python rpm module with python-2.7.5 on the same machine and not sure what is the proper way of doing that.
Python 2.7.5 was successfully installed. When calling 'import rpm' I got an import error.

I've found few RPMs for python-2.7.5 however, they are not good for RHEL5/OEL5 64 bit

Appreciate any pointers/advise!

Answer (score 1):

A good solution for Python 2.7 is to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/).

In a nutshell, virtualenv allows you to manage several versions of Python on the same computer (even the same user) without getting in each other's way. It also allows to have several "flavors" of the same Python version, each with a different set of modules.

The process is described in [detail in the documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#usage).

In your case, create an environment and then use `pip` to install the RPM module into this environment. When you activate the environment, Python scripts will be able to import the RPM module as long as you start them inside the environment (usually, the same terminal or shell process).

This will not affect the existing installation of 2.7 nor the old Python 2.4.

**[EDIT]** There is no pip module for `rpm-module`. Depending on how the module works, you should try to download the source RPM (`*.src.rpm`) and modify the SPEC file until it takes your Python 2.7 for the build and installs into the Python 2.7 module path.

**[EDIT2]** Steps to fix the problem:

1. I opened the tar `tar -zxvf rpm-4.4.2.3.tar.gz`
2. `vi configure` -----> changed all instances of `python2.5` to `python2.7`
3. `./autogen.sh`
4. `gmake`
5. `gmake -n install > log`
6. Check the `log` file to make sure it doesn't install in the wrong places.
7. `gmake install` to install for real

Comment: virtualenv allows you to download the **sources** for the rpm module and build + install them for Python 2.7 alone.

Comment: It doesn't exist. If you only need to parse RPM files, you can use one of the PIP modules for that. Or use the sources for Python 2.4 and patch them until they compile with Python 2.7.

Comment: In the End I patched the source for Python 2.4 and patches it to 2.7 as you suggested:
***** 1. I opened the tar (tar -zxvf rpm-4.4.2.3.tar.gz) ***** 
***** 2. vi configure -----> changed all instances of "python2.5" to  "python2.7" ***** 

*****  3. ./autogen.sh  ***** 

*****  4. gmake  ***** 

*****  5. gmake install ***** 

*****  Just wrote those steps to help other people :) *****